# Magit Log for Directory (git log -p -- /)

Tags: magit, logging

In git, the following shows patchlog for a directory

```
git log -p -- hukarz/
```

How can I do this in Magit?;)  I found some patch for it, but has this been included in Magit?

Here's [the patch](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/594) I found

```
    Modified   magit-key-mode.el
diff --git a/magit-key-mode.el b/magit-key-mode.el
index dd69988..e16e7bc 100644
--- a/magit-key-mode.el
+++ b/magit-key-mode.el
@@ -27,6 +27,7 @@
       ("l" "Short" magit-log)
       ("L" "Long" magit-log-long)
       ("h" "Reflog" magit-reflog)
+      ("p" "Paths" magit-log-for-paths)
       ("rl" "Ranged short" magit-log-ranged)
       ("rL" "Ranged long" magit-log-long-ranged)
       ("rh" "Ranged reflog" magit-reflog-ranged))
    Modified   magit.el
diff --git a/magit.el b/magit.el
index ad5569d..11d9f5d 100644
--- a/magit.el
+++ b/magit.el
@@ -2397,6 +2397,7 @@ magit-topgit and magit-svn"
     ("Log"
      ["Short Log" magit-log t]
      ["Long Log" magit-log-long t]
+     ["Files or directories" magit-log-for-paths t]
      ["Reflog" magit-reflog t]
      ["Extended..." magit-key-mode-popup-logging t])
     "---"
@@ -5229,6 +5230,11 @@ With a non numeric prefix ARG, show all entries"
     (magit-mode-init topdir 'magit-log-mode #'magit-refresh-log-buffer range
                      'long args)))

+(magit-define-command log-for-paths ()
+  (interactive)
+  (let ((paths (read-string "Files or directories: ")))
+    (apply 'magit-log nil "--" (split-string paths))))
+
```

Comment: I don't think there's been a `magit-key-mode.el` library in Magit since back in the version 1.x days, but in any case that patch doesn't look like it has anything to do with the `-p` option to `git log`.

Answer (score 1):

In current versions (and for a long time) these options are in the transient menu by default (`-p` is referred to by its long option name `--patch`).

So in the magit log transient menu, just type `-p` and `--`.